# How to add items in ComboBox from database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, combobox, items

Im trying to add items in the comboBox (`cmbInstructor`) namely the last names (`instructorLN`) however, my code does not seem to work. Any ideas on where I went wrong?

```
private void cmbInstructor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(mycon);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM instructor WHERE instructorType ='" + labelClass.Text + "'", conn);
    string instructorLN = "";

    conn.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        instructorLN = myReader["instructorLN"].ToString();
    }
    cmbInstructor.Items.Add(instructorLN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are adding *only* last value that your `SELECT` returns.

Move your

```
cmbInstructor.Items.Add(instructorLN);
```

line into to the while statement as;

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
    cmbInstructor.Items.Add(myReader["instructorLN"].ToString());
}
```

By the way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command and reader automatically.

```
using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(mycon))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM instructor WHERE instructorType = @type";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", labelClass.Text);

    conn.Open();
    using(var myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
             cmbInstructor.Items.Add(myReader["instructorLN"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...but it seems that the items still wont show

Comment: @jgf Why you using this code in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your combobox? Did you debug your code and see what's going on?